# When multiple a relative big floating point value with two relative small floating point value, what's the best order of arithmetic to eliminate error

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point, ieee-754

The question description itself is pretty simple, let's say i have two variable, the `big` and `scale`, all i want to do is calculating:

```cpp
float res = big * scale * scale;
```

As you can see, there exists two arithmetic order:

```cpp
// #1
float res = (big * scale) * scale;
// #2
float res = big * (scale * scale);
```

Due to the fact of IEEE754 single precision standard, it is natural that the above two line will give different result.

Now i have some priori knowledge that `big` might vary from `0` to `~1000`, `scale` might vary from `0` to `2^-10`. The `big` is not that "big" that might ["eat the small"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Addition_and_subtraction). And the `scale` is not that "small" to cause underflow when multiply themselves. That leaves my question is, which arithmetic order should i adopt to get a "smaller error", compared with the "real" value?

Comment: The second one: `big * (scale * scale)`

Comment: What order do ***you*** think is better, and why?

Comment: There should not be a lot of difference between the two (unlike when adding/subtracting numbers of different magnitude). The magnitude (i.e., the exponent part) of floating point numbers has no influence on the rounding error (as long as no over-/underflow happens).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your reply, i wonder if you can give me the brief reason?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I see no reason to prefer one over the other, if overflow and underflow can be ruled out. They will not always produce the same result, but which of them is more accurate depends on their mantissas, not their exponents.

Comment: @TonyK I must admit I was thinking of addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Order makes a possible small difference**

Since the concern is precision and not range:

Consider the number of non-zero significant bits in `big` and `scale`.  Each as `float`s may have up to 24 significant binary digits.

The idea is to perform the 2 multiplications and avoid 2 rounding.  If possible, do multiplication exactly first.  If `big` has fewer non-zero significant binary digits, then do `big * scale` first, else `scale * scale`.

As OP question hints that `scale` may be a power-of-2, then since that have only 1 significant binary digit, and if that holds for OP's code, then the order is irrelevant.

The exponent is irrelevant given OP's "scale is not that "small" to cause underflow when multiply themselves"

Since these are `float`, check `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as the issue may be moot as intermediate calculations may occur with wider math.

Answer (score 2):

From a precision standpoint - not much difference.

To avoid avoid *underflow* (product becomes 0.0), use `(big * scale) * scale;` as `scale * scale` may become 0.

I now see "... and the scale is not that "small" to cause underflow when multiply themselves. " -  oh well.

Comment: Will they? That just my guessing, in the limitation case, ```scale * scale``` might like ```2^-10 * 2^-10```

Comment: `scale` is in the range [0...2e-10].  That contradicts " scale is not that "small" to cause underflow when multiply themselves".  Which is it?  `scale = 1e-30` is in range yet `scale*scale` underflows.

Comment: ```2^-10 * 2^-10``` became ```4^-20```, that's bigger than ```1e-30```?

Comment: @user8510613: that should be `2^-20`, not `4^-20`.

Comment: @user8510613 Yes and `1e-30` in in the range 0 to 2^-10.  (I have type on comment above: should be `range [0...2e-10]` --> `range [0 to 2^-10]`.